# Problema com javascript basico

Tags: javascript, html, css

Boa noite, eu estou com um problema, pois o codigo seguinte não funciona:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var boxElement = document.querySelector('.box');

        boxElement.style.width = 100;
        boxElement.style.height = 100;
        boxElement.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Era para dar um resultado assim: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas não aparece nada: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O console não reporta nada, nenhum erro.
E parece estar tudo certo.

Answer (score 4):

Você precisa definir a medida do valor (PX, PT...)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var boxElement = document.querySelector('.box');

        boxElement.style.width = '100px';
        boxElement.style.height = '100px';
        boxElement.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Foi a primeira coisa que eu tentei.  Eu ouvi falar que nesse caso n precisa retornar medida,mas mesmo   assim tentei com px e n foi.

Comment: havia colocado aspas simples?

Comment: Não, boa, assim foi.
Porem eu vi em tutoriais as pessoas fazendo sem, so colocando o numero sem aspas, pq sera que no meu n funcionou?

Comment: Pq talvez vc tenha visto tutorial de jss (pré processador de css) ou algo do genêro, e não de js, talvez se compartilhasse mais informações de onde viu isso, pudessemos dar uma resposta mais objetiva do pq assim não funcionou